How to use sp_rename for an index with a target name that is the same in multiple tables
I am exploring the sp_rename procedure in MSSQL based on input provided in an answer to another question.
I have some 50 tables that has been created with a UID column having a random unique constraint name like "UQ__tblAssig__C5B19603C906D5BE". I want to rename theese constraints to exactly I_UID for all tables to comply with other indecies used in the different tables. Note that the index [I_UID] is not present in any of the tables beforehand. Running the first of theese three rows works fine, and I get an index I_UID in the index folder of tblAssignmentType.
EXEC sp_rename N'[tblAssignmentType].[UQ__tblAssig__C5B19603C906D5BE]', N'[I_UID]', N'INDEX';
EXEC sp_rename N'[tblProduct].[UQ__tblProdu__C5B196034878474D]', N'[I_UID]', N'INDEX';
EXEC sp_rename N'[tblAssignment].[UQ__tblAssig__C5B196031B17A97B]', N'[I_UID]', N'INDEX';

However when I run one of the next lines I get the following error msg:
Msg 15335, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 733 [Batch Start Line 38]
Error: The new name '[I_UID]' is already in use as a INDEX name and 
       would cause a duplicate that is not permitted.

But in tblProduct I do not have an index named I_UID. Therefore I suspect that the previous rename statement made a I_UID index in the global scope, even though it appers in the correct table.


Which brings me to the question:
What kind of syntax could I use with sp_rename to specify that the new name should be contained inside the scope of a certain table in such a way that the same local name also could be used for other tables afterwards?
EDIT FROM COMMENTS: I do not have a Constraint duplicating the name. It is also not relevant which of the three renaming I perform first, any second and third one will fail while the first one goes through. I can also change the target name to something entirely different like N'PeterPan', as long as it is the same for the three indexes it will only work for one of the statements. But it might indeed be some issues related to renaming an index created by CONSTRAINT UNIQUE when adding a column. Indeed I am able to rename any other index to a name that re-occurs in different tables.

Index names are already scoped just to a table. Your problem is that these are constraints not just indexes and renaming the index also renames the associated constraint - and constraint names are schema scoped. (Example) If this naming is important to you you need to replace them with unique indexes not created as constraints.
I don't think there is any way to do this conversion of a unique constraint to a simple decoupled unique index as a metatdata only operation though.
You would need to do this as
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX I_UID ON YourTable(UID) /*WITH (ONLINE = ON)*/;

And then drop the unwanted constraint on YourTable

You can SWITCH a table with a unique constraint to a table with a (differently named) unique index https://dbfiddle.uk/EPmq9qHy
